# error in installing apache libtool not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, svn, docker, libtool

I am installing the apache steps are as follow
echo deb http ://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports vivid restricted main multiverse universe  >> /etc/apt/sources.list 
apt-get install -y git \
openssl \
subversion \
autoconf \
libtool \
libapr \
libapr-util \
make \
libpcre3-dev \
libpcre++-dev \
libxml2-dev \
libexpat1-dev \
python

git clone https ://github.com/apache/httpd.git

cd httpd

svn co http: //svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr && cd srclib/apr && ./buildconf && ./build libtool && make && make install

The ./buildconf is giving error as follow 
./buildconf
found apr source: srclib/apr
rebuilding srclib/apr/configure
buildconf: checking installation...
buildconf: python version 2.7.9 (ok)
buildconf: autoconf version 2.69 (ok)
buildconf: libtool not found.
           You need libtool version 1.4 or newer installed
           to build APR from SVN.
./buildconf failed for apr


In above as i have already installed libtool. But the libttol is not found.when i say apt-get install -y libtool i get message as                         
       # apt-get install -y libtoo
apt-get install -y libtool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libtool is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/restricted ppc64el Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_vivid_restricted_binary-ppc64el_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/main ppc64el Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_vivid_main_binary-ppc64el_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

but when i try commands i get  $libtool
bash: libtool: command not found
$man libtool
bash: man: command not found
$libttol --help
bash: libttol: command not found
$libtool --version
bash: libtool: command not found

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**In Ubuntu vivid**, `/usr/bin/libtool` is provided by the `libtool-bin` package, not by the `libtool` package. Install `libtool-bin`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libtool-bin
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, voted your answer up because it is the correct answer

Comment: Leave it to Debian to have two packages: libtool (no libtool) and libtool-bin (has libtool). :(

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, it would be nice if the Apache Httpd's documentation would also mention libtool-bin (as it does for glibtool). `httpd/.travis.yml` already uses `libtool-bin`.

Comment: @AndreiDamian-Fekete As with most Open Source projects, *patches are always welcome*.